# How can I get a single line out?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
eni=soleloge.split("  ")

res = [int(sub.split(':')[1]) for sub in yeni]
```

there is only one line up here

```
solmatris=numpy.array(res)   
if solmatris.size>0:                            
   print(solmatris)
   f.write(solmatrisStr)
```

here the output is as follows:

> [  835   732   474   519   831   834   847   852   841   834   801
> -9344
> -3660 13808  1648  -463    86]

I want to out:

> [  835   732   474   519   831   834   847   852   841   834   801 -9344  -3660 13808  1648  -463    86 ]

After converting to matrix, I print out to notebook. I don't use console.

https://prnt.sc/10c0m85 I don't want it to be like this.

I apologize for not expressing my problem clearly at first.

Why does it give such a printout and how can I fix it.

Comment: "how can I fix it" What do you want the output to be instead?

Comment: numpy's representation of arrays has an automatic wrap-around that is not based on the window size.  You could do `print(*solmatris)` or `print(list(solmatris))` instead to get it on a single line.

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not express my problem clearly. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @AlainT. Will you post this as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, was originally an answer but I got blocked by trigger happy question closers before I could post it.  Added back as an answer now that the question is reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `numpy.array` type cast and instead try this `print(', '.join(str(r) for r in res))`.

Answer (score 1):

numpy's representation of arrays has an automatic wrap-around that is not based on the window size. You could do `print(*solmatris)` or `print(list(solmatris))` instead to get it on a single line.

Comment: Thnk u very much for your answer. Unfortunately, Console does not solve my problem of the screen showing a single line. I keep a record of the printouts in a notebook.

Comment: I looked at the notebook picture you added and there seems to be a discrepancy between the end of line character conventions.  It looks like the program separates lines with a single <LF> but the notebook expects <CR><LF> (or inversely).  This was a problem often seen in the past when exchanging text files between Windows and Unix systems.

Comment: I thought the data type does not matter on the Spyder since I printed the results in notepad. I decided to turn the data into a list and keep it in a public list and print it to notepad with the for loop. Inspired by `print (list (solmatris))`  command. Thank you very much for your help.